# Explain query Mysql

Tags: mysql, explain

I have the following query

```
select count(inspection_result) 
from test 
where (inspection_time between "2015-07-14 00:00:00" and "2015-07-14 00:59:59" )
    and  inspection_result= 0 and  part_type = "39000048"  and location = "1"
```

When I execute `Explain` it gives me the exact row that is `352` which is same as count result.
But when I execute explain on the following query

```
select count(inspection_result) 
from test 
where (inspection_time between "2015-07-14 00:00:00" and "2015-07-14 00:59:59" )
and  inspection_result= 1 and  part_type = "39000048"  and location = "1"
```

The number of rows it shows `393397`, whereas the output is `71280`.
Thus, it affecting my query speed. Can anyone help me why such behaviour of the query.

Comment: Explain does not tell you how many rows the result will be, it tells you an estimate of the rows it needs to examine according to the histogram information available for the given table(s) and indexes. Based on the histogram information it determines if the indexes are used and which are used. If they are not used, or others are used, explain plan information can differ.

Comment: Your table must have lots of rows with `inspection_result = 1`, so the second query has to examine more rows.

Comment: You could try adding indexes on the other columns in the query, or making a composite index on all the tables.

Comment: The composite key is already present. The composite key consists of (part_name, inpection_result, location, inspection_time).inspection_time is primary key . inspection_result, location and part_type are indexed individually.

Comment: The key_len = 316 .Is it good for optimization?